# How to use the Bass library to convert audio to another format (using C#)

Tags: c#, audio, bass

Good day everyone and happy holidays.

I'm trying to create a "simple" program that allows me to create a list of video files (Youtube video's to be precise) that are then run through by my program and converted any given format to pure MP3 audio. For this purpose I'm trying to use the BASS.dll and well it isn't going so well.

I was wondering if anyone has used BASS to convert from one audio format to another?
Or is there another library better suited for this?

Comment: Okay this project is going to be put on ice until I have done some more research if I ever finish this I will post it here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly then the input files are YouTube videos which are FLV or F4V (MP4).  Does BASS even support those formats?

Depending on your requirements, the easiest way might be to use Process.Start with ffmpeg to perform the extraction/conversion.  Windows builds here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mplayer-win32/files/FFmpeg/

Comment: I was never sure if BASS would work, most threads I found about audio conversion seemed either to use LAME or BASS. But then the question is how do I use ffmpeg instead, I mean how do I install it properly? And can I make it part of my C# application, so I don't need to have ffmpeg with me at all times?

Comment: ffmpeg is a single (albeit big) executable that you could include with (not inside) your app.  Example command line to extract the audio: "ffmpeg -i video.flv -ab 128 audio.mp3".  As for ways to do this that are fully contained in your executable, I'm not sure.